# Prevent Jekyll from creating a page link from a static file

Tags: r, git, jekyll, r-markdown

I have a class site hosted through GitHub project pages and built with Jekyll. The issue is that I want to have a R Markdown file (`.Rmd`, markdown with R code) as a static file for the students to download, but Jekyll keeps linking it as a page as if it was in the root directory of my site and a `.md`

Like this:

[image: banner image]

[Here's the repo](https://github.com/dnedveck/biol3272) of the site (in the gh-pages branch), there's a link in the README for where it is live.

Comment: It seems to working fine. I was able to download the markdown template on OS X

Comment: Same here linked to */assets/RMarkdownTemplate.Rmd* and transfered (downloaded) as BIN file.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't want it to be shown there, I want it to exist in `/assets/` and then link to it from another page. I don't want the behavior where Jekyll is making the link in the top part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing that because that file has front matter (and a title in the front matter to be more specific), and your header file (_includes/header.html) is building the main navigation automatically like this:

`{% for my_page in site.pages %}
          {% if my_page.title %}
          <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}`

if you remove the front matter it won't end up there. If you need the front matter you can just change the way the nav is built, maybe by adding something like mainnav: true to the front matter of the files you want to end up in the main nav. Then you could change the if statement to be `if my_page.mainnav`.

I don't really like the way that main nav is built, I think it is just an example, it can be built in a bunch of ways, you probably would want more control that just having any file with front matter and a title ending up there.

Comment: Thanks! So, do you know if there is an option for jekyll to just copy a directory into the final site, but ignore the files within? I've tried to use `keep_files: [assets]` in my `_config.yml`, but it doesn't seem to leaving the content in assets alone (it's still parsing the front matter) ....

Comment: if there is front matter, jekyll processes them and looks for things to do to it. If there is no front matter then jekyll just copies it to the same location in the _site directory. So images just get copied, if you have an .md file and it has no front matter then it should behave the same way - just get copied to the same directory in _site. If you just want them copied why do you need the front matter?

Comment: keep_files is a little vague - when generating the site at build time, jekyll will completely clean out the _site folder. keep_files is supposed to have jekyll not delete a folder/file from the _site folder when it goes to wipe it out at build time. I'm not sure what the use case is for this. It may do what you want if you stick the folder full of files in the _site folder, not the main folder. But I would think this is a bad idea unless it is a huge number of files that slow down the build.

Comment: The document has front matter for a different system (compiling with knitr in R). I'm looking to host the file for students to download, and having them add the front matter would be a pain since this is going to be pretty common in the future.

Comment: ah, the front matter is disapearing on the file they are downloading - that is the real problem right? maybe you could put them in a collection, then have all collection items go thru a layout that then adds back the front matter? no idea if that would work, but it might.

Comment: meh, that won't work as the extension will change. The Keep_files thing might be the way to do it, it just seems dangerous as the _site folder to me is disposable so keeping things in it is an odd idea to me. To use keep_files I would use a different folder than assets - one that doesn't exist in the main project and put it in the _site folder, not the parent folder.

Comment: hmm, unfortunate about the `keep_files` thing, I would hope there would be a simpler solution than modifying the `header.html`,  but thanks for pointing me in that direction. I'll try that out and report back.